# JS OOP and Forced Overriding

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm building an object which will have a "buildVisuals()" method. Depending on the context, "buildVisuals()" could create a google maps marker, or fill out an html template, or any of a number things that future me might decide to make it do. But, if visualization is available in any context, I want it to execute on creation.

```
thing = function(){
   var x, y, z;
   this.buildVisuals();
}

...

new thing();
```

Currently, I'm considering leaving this method empty and forcing the contexts that utilize it to over-ride the method so that only the contexts that require maps, or whatever, can have the functionality they need, and for those context don't require immediate visualization they can leave it blank.

Problem: I don't know what this pattern is called, I don't know if it's more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: It sounds kind of like the Factory pattern. You call the constructor of a base class, and depending on the parameters it chooses which descendant class it actually constructs.

Comment: "Forced overriding" sounds interface-ish to me.

Comment: abstract / virtual / mustInherit methods or class are the words used in various languages. You could define a default buildVisual that would just throw an exception to enforce that pattern.

Comment: yes! I forgot about abstract methods. That is exactly what it is. Not so much of a pattern I guess?

Comment: Well i guess throwing a clear exception could be a clean way. You could think also about injection here, with a constructor like : thing = new Thing( someBuildVisualFunction ) ; or thing = new Thing( someVisualHandlingClass ) ;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ideas comes to mind when reading your question :
  You can either consider the buildVisuals method as an `abstract` / `virtual` / `mustInherit` method.

```
// Abstract Base class
function Handler() {
   this.visuals = this.buildVisuals();
}

Handler.prototype = {
  doAThing : function() {
  },
  buildVisuals : function () {
     throw('Error : buildVisuals was not overloaded');
  }
};

// Real class inheriting from the base class
function HTMLHandler() {
    Handler.call(this);
}

HTMLHandler.prototype = Object.create(Handler.prototype);

// overloading (defining) buildVisual
HTMLHandler.prototype.buildVisuals = function() {
   // Real code here
};

// now you create with : 
var myHandler = new HTMLHandler();

// notice that the following line would throw :
// var myThrowingHandler = new Handler();
```

But i'd prefer the injection pattern, and i'd even prefer it by injecting a class that handles the visual.

```
//  --------------
function Handler( visualHandlingClass ) {

  this.visualHandler = new visualHandlingClass( /* maybe some params here */ );

}

Handler.prototype = {   ...  } ;    

//  --------------

function HTMLVisualHandler () {
    // class constructor here...
}

HTMLVisualHandler.prototype = {   ...   } ;

//  ---------------
var HandlerUsingHtml = new Handler ( HTMLVisualHandler ) ;
```

Now if you want to choose with a string for some reason, you might want either to use the factory pattern to get your instance, but a simple helper function is good enough :

```
function provideHandler( outputKindString ) {
     if (outputKindString == 'html') {
        return new Handler ( HTMLVisualHandler ) ;
     } 
     if (  ....  )
 }

var myHandler = provideHandler( 'html' );
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Barmar noted, it looks like the [Factory](http://www.dofactory.com/javascript/factory-method-design-pattern) design pattern.
From the online [book](http://Learning%20JavaScript%20Design%20Patterns):

> **When To Use The Factory Pattern**
>
> - When we're working with many small objects or components that share the same properties.
> - When we need to easily generate different instances of objects depending on the environment we are in.

Comment: I can see it now. The forcing the override in this way is pretty much a more naive version of the example factory in your link... Now to decide exactly how naive I want it.

Comment: The Factory pattern is when you call a function and pass it a string (or some other type of indication) about the object it should create and then it spits out that type of object. I don't think that's what the OP is doing. I think the OP *is* creating separate classes that inherit from `thing` *but* i think he is calling their constructors *himself*.

Comment: @LukeP Why are you explaining the meaning of the Factory pattern? Aren't the links enough?

Comment: I thought maybe I should sum it up for you, because you state that what he is doing looks like the factory pattern, so  I was not sure if you interpreted his intended implementation strategy differently than I did, or if you just didn't understand the factory pattern.    Also, whats the harm of having a 1 sentence summary there for future readers? You should always add expanation where applicable .

Comment: @LukeP Your initial comment / suggestion is based solely on your assumptions - useless poker technique in the IT context. Nevertheless, thanks for the "enlightenment" - now we can see in the dark.

Comment: I think your misinterpreting my demeanor as hostile. I never said your interpretation of OP's intent was wrong, nor did I down vote your answer. I was merely contributing my perspective. I don't understand what you mean by "poker technique" either.

Comment: @LukeP I meant the fuzzy approach which works for some Q and doesn't for others.

Comment: I still don't get it. Are you talking about the part where I stated that my opinion about the OP's intent is different from yours?

Comment: @LukeP Did you fully understand the Q? No. Did you ask the OP himself? No. That's what's called a fuzzy approach.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85342/discussion-between-lukep-and-vidul).